# Adobe Illustrator - File - Icon Preview

Tags: adobe-illustrator

When I save my Illustrator file the file preview shows like this. How can I change it? At the moment it is showing many different layers in the document.

I want it to be the cover only - which is on one layer with sublayers.

Thanks

[image]

Answer (score 1):

Rasterise a copy of the desired image an place it on top Layer.

This will make only that Layer visible.

The Mac viewer always shows all the Layers.

If you move the undesired content to another artboard works fine too, cause it will be shown only the arboard one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I did all of this - second artboard, moved all layers/sublayers to second artboard other than my cover. Rasterize my cover which create a sublayer <image> on one layer on artboard 1. Saved as a new file for good measure. Did not work. Curiously it showed Artboard 2, one Layer and all its sublayers. Any thoughts? Thanks

Comment: I figured it out. One has to make sure that the second artboard is far enough away from the first such that none of the art on artboard 2 overlaps onto art 1. Thanks